# IntelliJ not refreshing file status?

Tags: git, intellij-idea

I am working on a Windows machine.

When I open a CRLF file in IntelliJ, hit enter and then backspace (nothing should change), IntelliJ marks the file as edited (blue).

If I try to commit the changes it says:

> Contents have differences only in line separators

If I try to execute `git status`, I can see that Git works properly and reports no files changed.

It seems like IntelliJ does not refresh the file until I go to:

> VCS -> Refresh File Status

Then, it shows the file as unchanged.

Even if I refresh the file status manually after hitting enter, and before hitting backspace, it shows the file as unchanged, as it should.

This is my git config file from `C:/ProgramData/Git/` with `autocrlf=true`.

```
[core]
    symlinks = false
    autocrlf = true
    fscache = true
[color]
    diff = auto
    status = auto
    branch = auto
    interactive = true
[help]
    format = html
[rebase]
    autosquash = true
```

Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely it is the following issue:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-175622

Has been fixed already, the fix should be included into 2017.2.3